# How to show the battery percentage remaining in numbers?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, battery

At the moment Android 2.2 has a pretty incomprehensible icon of a battery that shows remaining strength.

Is there a way to switch that to a numeric display (like is available on the iPhone)?

Answer (score 8):

if you use cyanogenmod, there's an option to show numeric battery percentage, and numeric signal strength in dbm on the status bar

Comment: That's good to know, I keep meaning to checkout cyanogenmod.

Comment: +1, far more useful than having a little battery bar icon alone IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

Battery indicator is a free app that does this: https://www.appbrain.com/app/com.darshancomputing.BatteryIndicator

Unfortunately, it doesn't replace the stock icon, it just adds another that displays the numbers.  I'm not aware of any way to replace or change the stock icon, even with root access.

Answer (score 3):

Press menu > Settings > About phone (scroll Down) > Status.
There's an item called Battery level, which shows the currrent battery level in %.
Also the part Battery use might be interesting. You'll find a list with Items that use the most battery there.

Answer (score -2):

`Settings > Display > More settings > Display battery as percentage`.

Comment: This is not part of stock Android, are you using a custom ROM?